# SQL 0 results for 'Not In' and 'In' when row does exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, select-query

I have a table (A) with a list of order numbers. It contains a single row.

Once this order has been processed it should be deleted. However, it is failing to be deleted.

I began investigating, a really simple query is performed for the deletion.

`delete from table(A) where orderno not in (select distinct orderno from tableB)`

The order number absolutely does not exist in tableB.

I changed the query in SSMS to :

`select * from table(A) where orderno not in (select distinct orderno from tableB)`

This returned 0 rows. Bare in mind the orderno does exist in tableA.
I then changed the query from "not in" to "In". It still returned 0 rows. How can this be possible that a value is not in a list of values but also not show for the opposite?

Things I have tried:

- Two additional developers to look over it.
- ltrim(rtrim()) on both the select values.
- Various char casts and casting the number as an int.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Add `... where orderno  is not null` to the sub-query. Or, even better, switch to `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `NOT IN` with a subquery.  Use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
delete from tableA 
    where not exists (select 1 from tableB where tableA.orderno = tableB.orderno);
```

What is the difference?  If *any* `orderno` in `TableB` is `NULL`, then `NOT IN` returns `NULL`.  This is correct behavior based on how `NULL` is defined in SQL, but it is counterintuitive.  `NOT EXISTS` does what you want.

Comment: This is exactly the cause. There were null records. We did pick up on this and removed them. However we continued testing and still came up with no results. But what had actually happened was that the service running in the background now managed to find a match and had already removed it. Leading us to believe the query was still not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`

```
select * 
from table(A) a
where not exists (selet 1 from tableB where orderno = a.orderno);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same.
try joining the two tables tableA and TableB

```
select * from TableA a  
inner join TableB b on a.orderno =b.orderno
```

This should allow you to get the records and then you can delete the same.